# ¿Cómo se puede hacer una tabla en C++ con una matriz y además ordenarla de mayor a menor?

Tags: c++, tablas, tabla-dinámica

Hace poco empecé a programar en C++, y necesito hacer una "tabla" de equipos de fútbol que sea de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte señalada en azul es una matriz de 4x8 que se llena con datos (que pueden cambiar) que se obtienen de otra parte del código que ya tengo hecho.

Lo que está señalado con color amarillo tiene que ser información fija.

Y el problema es que no sé exactamente como hacer que la parte que está señalada en rojo me quede a la par de la matriz. Porque además tengo que hacer que la tabla esté ordenada específicamente de manera que el equipo con más puntos esté primero y así con los demás. (Por ejemplo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento el código (específicamente de esta parte) lo tengo de esta forma:

```
cout << "\n\tEquipo" << setw(6) << "PJ" << setw(4) << "PG" << setw(4) << "PE" << setw(4) << "PP" 

     << setw(4) << "GF" << setw(4) << "GC" << setw(5) << "Dif" << setw(5) << "Pts" << endl; (Todo esto es una misma línea de código, lo que pasa es que ahora mismo que estoy escribiendo esto se ve así, luego de esta línea viene lo de abajo)

cout << "1." << Equipo1 << endl;
cout << "2." << Equipo2 << endl;
cout << "3." << Equipo3 << endl;
cout << "4." << Equipo4 << endl;  
                                                  
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
        cout <<"|"<<Matriz[i][j]<<"|";
        if(Matriz[i][j] >= 0){
            cout <<" ";
        }
        if(Matriz[i][j] < 0){
            cout <<"";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Pero evidentemente esto está mal porque a la hora de ejecutarlo se ve de esta forma (y obviamente tampoco está ordenado porque sinceramente no sé muy bien como hacerlo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso alguien me puede decir por favor, como hacer para que quede a la par o "adjunto" a la parte donde aparece el nombre de los equipos y además que queden ordenados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues tal y como lo tienes puedes, como solución chapucera, crear una función que te imprima una de las filas de la matriz:

```
void imprimir_fila(int matriz[][8], int fila)
{
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
        cout <<"|"<<matriz[fila][j]<<"|";
        if(matriz[fila][j] >= 0){
            cout <<" ";
        } else {
            cout <<"";
        }
    }
}
```

Con lo cual ahora ya no tienes que repetir el código a la hora de imprimir las 4 filas:

```
cout << "1." << Equipo1;
imprimir_fila(0);
cout << '\n';

cout << "2." << Equipo2;
imprimir_fila(1);
cout << '\n';

cout << "3." << Equipo3;
imprimir_fila(2);
cout << '\n';

cout << "4." << Equipo4;
imprimir_fila(3);
cout << '\n';
```

Sin embargo, el código quedaría más elegante si creases una estructura de datos que almacenase también el nombre del equipo:

```
struct Equipo
{
    std::string nombre;
    int datos[8];
};
```

Aunque si es un requisito seguir utilizando la matriz, también podrías referenciarla:

```
struct Equipo
{
    std::string nombre;
    int * datos;
};
```

En este caso el array podrías crearlo así:

```
Equipo equipos[] = { {Equipo1, Matriz[0]}, {Equipo2, Matriz[1]}, {Equipo3, Matriz[2]}, {Equipo4, Matriz[3]} };
```

Aunque sería preferible utilizar un contenedor de la STL, tipo `std::vector` o `std::array`

En cualquier caso, ahora ya podrías imprimir toda la tabla con un único bucle:

```
int pos = 1;
for(Equipo const& equipo : equipos)
{
    std::cout << pos << '.' << equipo.nombre << ' ';
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout <<"|"<<equipo.datos[j]<<"|";
        if(equipo.datos[j] >= 0){
            cout <<" ";
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias.